# Array items to properties of objects in array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have an array of items `arr = ['1a', '2b', '3c', '4d']` and some id `id = 'sasaas'`. Now I want to make an array of objects such that elements of `arr` would be properties on objects inside new array, like

```
[
  {'id1' : id, 'id2': '1a'}
  {'id1' : id, 'id2': '2b'}
  {'id1' : id, 'id2': '3c'}
  {'id1' : id, 'id2': '4c'}
]
```

I tried this

```
let arr = ['1a', '2b', '3c', '4d'];
let id = 'sasaas';
let c = arr.map(i => {'id1': id, 'id2': i})
```

but it didn't work. I don't what I'm doing wrong here, any Idea?

Comment: Add `()` (parentheses) around those braces in the lambda

Comment: As a side note and general advice - as a programmer, never use the words "it doesn't work" - explain exactly what happens, the phrase "doesn't work" serves no purpose other than to waste time.

Comment: `arr.map(i => {'id1': id, 'id2': i})` -> `arr.map(i => ({'id1': id, 'id2': i}))` or `arr.map(i => { return {'id1': id, 'id2': i}; })`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will give you the array you desire.

```
let arr = ['1a', '2b', '3c', '4d'];
let id = 'sasaas';
let c = []
arr.forEach(i => c.push({'id1': id, 'id2': i}))
```

Use **forEach** instead of .map as @Chase said it has some side effects

Comment: Please refrain from suggesting the use of `.map` in this way. It is generally considered bad practice to use `.map` for side effects. Side effects is the opposite of functional programming.

Comment: Please don't use `.map()` for simple iteration. Use `forEach()` or an actual loop.